# Is there a difference between terms "Get Latest" and "Check-out" in PerForce terminology?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am trying to get used to Perforce after using SVN where I was mostly using Commit and Get Latest.

But in perforce I am kind of confused.

What is the difference between terms `Get Latest` and `Check-out` in PerForce terminology?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From "[Perforce Basic Concepts](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4plugins/01_concepts.html)":

- Get Latest (`p4 sync`) is about transferring files from the depot to your workspace.
- Check-out (`p4 edit`) is about getting the latest version from the depot for *editing*.
  When files are checked out for edit, their permissions are set to read-write. When files are not checked out, Perforce sets them to read-only.

As mentioned in "[Perforce not syncing files correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807979/perforce-not-syncing-files-correctly)", a refresh (`p4 sync`) will update only files that are not opened (checked out) even when "Force Operation" is enabled. (`p4 sync -f`).
So the true difference is that a "check out" marks a file as being modified, and protect it from any refresh (any "get latest" operation).

[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4405/mark) comments (and amend the "difference" I just mentioned above):

> If you run a "`get latest`" (or `sync`) **on a file that is newer than the version that you have open for edit**, that will **set up a resolve conflict** that needs to be dealt with.
>   So while the file won't be updated by a sync directly, Perforce will set up the conflict so that it can be updated by doing a resolve (and in fact, the resolve must be done before a file open for edit can be submitted).

Comment: For completeness, it should be noted that if you run a "get latest" (or sync) on a file that is newer than the version that you have open for edit, that will set up a resolve conflict that needs to be dealt with.  So while the file won't be updated by a sync directly, Perforce will set up the conflict so that it can be updated by doing a resolve (and in fact, the resolve must be done before a file open for edit can be submitted).