# Perforce: how to get missing file from Depot to Workspace?

Tags: perforce, p4v

A given file is missing from my Workspace, but present at the Perforce Depot.

I tried several times to "Get Revision" and checked on the "Force Operation" flag. It always retrieve hundreds of files but not this one missing, which, by the way, is an .sln file.

Extra details that may be relevant: a) I use P4V; b) I usually open this project for editing in Visual Studio 2010 using the option "Open from Source Control"; c) I tried checking out all files in my solution and reverting unchanged files afterwards as an attempt to bring all files, but didn't work for this missing file of mine.

Does anyone have seen something similar?
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Get Revision" with "Force Operation" was not working because the file in question was checked out.
After reverting this file, I could get it by forcing the Get Revision.

This idea actually came from an answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807979/perforce-not-syncing-files-correctly) to which I came back to.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why the "force operation" might be necessary? Same thing happened to me for a new file that had been added, and I had never had locally. Why would I not just get it in a normal "Get Revision" or "Get Latest", like with all other new and updated files?

Answer (score 2):

1. Is the latest revision deleted for some reason? If you have "Show Deleted Depot Files" in the filter, above the workspace selector in P4V, it may appear to be there, but will be deleted.
2. Is your workspace correct? Is it mapped to a different folder then where you think?

An easy way to test, highlight the .sln file in P4V depot view, then hit ctrl+shift+s this will open an explorer window, in the directory where the file is.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 are not the case: 1) the latest revision is not deleted (neither marked to be deleted), in both the Workspace and Depot; 2) the mapping was correct, I double checked it.

Comment: Did you do the test I suggested? Also, have you tried from the command line? I usually get more info from the command line then I do from p4v.

Comment: Yes, I opened the explorer window to confirm the file was not present locally.

Answer (score 0):

Just covering all the bases: Do you have Visual Studio open while you're trying to do this?  If so there's a chance that the target folder/file is locked and so Perforce can't write there.

Comment: Good point! I couldn't check it though because I don't have the same scenario as before.